# Onclick change div image along with background color

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image as a button inside a div. By default, I am displaying image1 with background green when I click on the div I should change the background colour to blue and change to image2. Right now I am able to only change the colour but not the image. How to change both image and background colour ?

```js
var count = 0;
        
        function setColor(id) {
            var property = document.getElementById(id);
            if (count == 0) {
                property.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                document.getElementById('1').src = '~/Images/Icons/image1.png';
                count = 1;
            } else {
                property.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                document.getElementById('1').src = '~/Images/Icons/image2.png';
                count=0
            }
        }
```

```css
.buttonclass {
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 margin-top: 2px;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100000;
 border: solid 1px #777;
 background-color: green;
 padding: 0px;

}
```

```html
<div class="buttonclass" id="1" onclick="setColor(1);" >
    <img id="1" src="~/Images/Icons/image1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Check out if my answer works for you... running the snippet it's possible to see image toggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you have duplicate ids.

As seen [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp):
An ID should be unique within a page. However, if more than one element with the specified ID exists, the getElementById() method returns the first element in the source code.

You can append something to make them different. Also, i took permission to change status logic.

```js
var initial = true;
        
function setColor(id) {
    var property = document.getElementById(id+"div");
    var propertyImg = document.getElementById(id+"img");
    if (initial) {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        propertyImg.src = '~/Images/Icons/image1.png';
    } else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        propertyImg.src = '~/Images/Icons/image2.png';
    }
    initial = !initial;
}
```

```css
.buttonclass {
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 margin-top: 2px;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100000;
 border: solid 1px #777;
 background-color: green;
 padding: 0px;

}
```

```html
<div class="buttonclass" id="1div" onclick="setColor(1);" >
    <img id="1img" src="~/Images/Icons/image1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. You are right I was using same ids.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a variable called 'property', you can use that.

Change your JavaScript to:

```
var count = 0;  

    function setColor(id) {
        var property = document.getElementById(id);
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            property.src = '~/Images/Icons/image1.png';
            count = 1;
        } else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            property.src = '~/Images/Icons/image2.png';
            count=0
        }
    }
```

Or you can shorten this to:

```
var count = 0;
const COLORS = [
    "blue",
    "green"
];

function setColor(id) {
    var property = document.getElementById(id);

    property.style.backgroundColor = COLORS[count]
    property.src = ('~/Images/Icons/image' + count + '.png';

    var count = count == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```